# SqsListener Header take message body instead message attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, spring-messaging

I have code below to receive message and an attribute from the AWS SQS. The message body is as expected. However, the attribute "sourceId" is always taking the message body json as value.

```
@SqsListener(value = "my_queue", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
public void receive(MyEvent event, @Header("srcId") String srcId){
    log.error("abc -> " + srcId);
    ......
}
```

Below is what's in my configuration file

```
@Bean
public QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate(
        AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync) {
    return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSQSAsync);
}

@Bean
public QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMessageHandlerFactory(
        final ObjectMapper mapper, final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync){

    final QueueMessageHandlerFactory factory = new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();
    factory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync);
    factory.setArgumentResolvers(Arrays.asList(
                    new PayloadMethodArgumentResolver(myConverter(mapper)),
                    new HeaderMethodArgumentResolver(null, null)
    ));
    return factory;
}

private MessageConverter myConverter(final ObjectMapper mapper){

    final MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
    return converter;
}
```

When I send the below aws cli comand

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sqs send-message  --queue-url http://localhost:4566/000000000000/my_queue  --message-body '{ "id": "d8b636dc-dab3-73b9-50ed-606bdd92ba89", "status": "DISABLED"}'  --message-attributes '{ "srcId":{"DataType":"String","StringValue":"val1"}}'
```

The logging from the code is as below, while I expect "abc -> val1"

```
2023-05-16 16:09:23 2023-05-16 23:09:23.095 ERROR  --- c.c.messaging.SqsListeners       : abc -> { "id": "d8b636dc-dab3-73b9-50ed-606bdd92ba89","status": "DISABLED"}
```

Please help!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but once I switch the position of the  PayloadMethodArgumentResolver(myConverter(mapper)) and HeaderMethodArgumentResolver(null, null) in the list. The code start to work. Any one knows the reason? Please comment.